# Can long-running std::asyncs starve other std::asyncs?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, stdasync

As I understand it, usual implementations of std::async schedule these jobs on threads from a pre-allocated thread pool.

So lets say I first create and schedule enough long-running `std::async`s to keep all threads from that thread pool occupied. Directly afterwards (before long they finished executing) I also create and schedule some short-running `std::async`s. Could it happen that the short-running ones aren't executed at all until at least one of the long-running ones has finished? Or is there some guarantee in the standard (specifically C++11) that prevents this kind of situation (like spawning more threads so that the OS can schedule them in a round-robin fasion)?

Comment: It is implementation dependant.  Are you asking about the C++ standard or some particular implementation?

Comment: Ideally I'd like a guarantee from the standard. But since you seem to be saying that there's no such guarantee, I'm specifically interested in the behavior of GCC's libstdc++ (GCC 5.4, if that matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard reads:

> [[futures.async#3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/futures.async#3.1)] If launch​::​async is set in policy, calls `INVOKE(DECAY_­COPY(std​::​forward<F>(f)), DECAY_­COPY(std​::​forward<Args>(args))...)` ([func.require], [thread.thread.constr]) **as if in a new thread of execution represented by a thread object with the calls to DECAY_­COPY being evaluated in the thread that called async.**[...]

so, under the *as-if* rule, **new** threads must be spawned when `async()` is invoked with `​async` launch policy. Of course, an implementation may use a thread pool internally but, usual thread creation overhead aside, no special 'starving' can occur. Moreover, things like the initialization of thread locals should always happen.

In fact, clang libc++ trunk async implementation reads:

```
unique_ptr<__async_assoc_state<_Rp, _Fp>, __release_shared_count>
        __h(new __async_assoc_state<_Rp, _Fp>(_VSTD::forward<_Fp>(__f)));

VSTD::thread(&__async_assoc_state<_Rp, _Fp>::__execute, __h.get()).detach();

return future<_Rp>(__h.get());
```

as you can see, no 'explicit' thread pool is used internally.

Moreover, as you can read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/libstdc++/api/a01286_source.html#1654) also the libstdc++ implementation shipping with gcc 5.4.0 just invokes a plain thread.

Comment: Although if the policy is `launch​::​async | launch​::​deferred` (the default) the implementation may choose between either

Comment: @Caleth, yep, I assumed the question concerned with launch::async calls only (otherwise, the question would make little sense). BTW, there are also implementation provided launch policies as well ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MSVC's `std::async` seem to have exactly that property, at least as of MSVC2015.

I don't know if they fixed it in an 2017 update.

This is against the spirit of the standard.  However, the standard is extremely vague about thread forward progress guarantees (at least as of C++14).  So while `std::async` must behave as if it wraps a `std::thread`, the guarantees on `std::thread` forward progress are sufficiently weak that this isn't much of a guarantee under the as-if rule.

In practice, this has led me to replace `std::async` in my thread pool implementations with raw calls to `std::thread`, as raw use of `std::thread` in MSVC2015 doesn't appear to have that problem.

I find that a thread pool (with a task queue) is far more practical than raw calls to either `std::async` or `std::thread`, and as it is really easy to write a thread pool with either `std::thread` or `std::async`, I'd advise writing one with `std::thread`.

Your thread pool can return `std::future`s just like `std::async` does (but without the auto-blocking on destruction feature, as the pool itself manages the thread lifetimes).

I have read that C++17 added better forward progress guarantees, but I lack sufficient understanding to conclude if MSVC's behavior is now against the standard requirements.

Comment: *"the guarantees on std::thread forward progress are sufficiently weak that this isn't much of a guarantee under the as-if rule"* I'm not sure this is convincing; the letter of the standard says that the observable effect of async should be that of a new thread of execution; conversely, a program running under the MSVC implementation can gather observable evidence that async() calls behave differently from equivalent thread calls (this happens *indipendently* of thread execution progress guarantees).

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Except the standard *doesn't guarantee that `std::thread` behaves reasonably*.  Neither behaves differently than the standard guarantees a `std::thread` will behave.  Only behaviour in ways outside of the abstract machine behavior differs.  Observable behavior must be in the sense of "in terms of the abstract machine and behavior mandated by this standard"; other things (like if you do a stack trace) obviously cannot be identical.  As it happens, underspecified forward progress guarantees means that `std::thread` could be just as bad as `async` is...

Comment: yes, and “thread(foo).detach();bar();” *could* behave as “thread(foo).join();bar() under as-if rule, yet can we conclude that these two codes are *equivalent* as by the as-if rule?